# Is having concrete bonding primer on top of a layer of concrete stain ok?

Tags: concrete, stain, preparation

I had a bit of a lapse in reason when redoing my concrete floor. I ground down the floor, let it dry, and then applied a concrete stain (two coats). Then, because I wasn't thinking,  I applied Behr 880 concrete bonding primer to the top, thinking that it was a sealant.

Will having bonding primer on top of the surface be a problem? It looks completely fine, I just want to make sure having the primer on there won't cause dirt/dust to stick and accumulate, ultimately changing the floors in a short period of time. If having the primer on top is a problem, what are some ways to remove it?

Thanks for answering my bizarre question.